# highcharts and different yAxis for different categories

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts to draw column chart with the following data: 
- I have three categories: apples, oranges, peaches
- I have three data series for it: `[1, 10, 100], [2, 9, 120], [1, 11, 150]`

As you can see y values for different categories have completely different scales and I would like to show them accordingly. I'd like to show three groups of three columns, like this:

`1, 2, 1   ---   10, 9, 11   ---   100, 120, 150`

But also make sure first group is not completely squeezed into the ground because of the lower values.

Is it possible with highcharts?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [dual-axis chart example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes). Basically, you just need to make sure that you define your data in separate series, with different y-axes.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    //...
    yAxis: [
        //your yAxis definitions
    ],

    series: [{
        name: "Apples",
        yAxis: 0, //the index of the yAxis definition you want to use
        data: [1,2,1]
    }, {
        name: "Oranges",
        data: [10,9,11]
    }, {
        name: "Peaches",
        data: [100,120,150]
    }]
})
```

Comment: But then they will be grouped like this: 1-10-100, then second group 2.9,120 and third 1,1,150. Right? And I am trying to group them differently.

Comment: What dp the three series represent? If they are time periods, then name the series above as the time periods, and add `categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Peaches']` to your yAxis definition.